# CsvHelper Format Decimal using ClassMap

Tags: csvhelper

I have column columns in the file that will have values like "000120000" that needs to be converted into "1200.00" using CsvHelper ClassMap. I am currently using Decimal type for those columns and have the NumberStyle in the ClassMap that is truncating the zero's at the beginning. So i am getting the value as "120000". I tried using the "TypeConverterOption.Format("0.00")" but no luck. So would like to know if there is a way i can convert the value "120000" to "1200.00" using ClassMap. I can even divide by 100 but don't want to do this everywhere i use the field so need to do this logic in the ClassMap. Thank you in advance for helping me out on this.

**In the ClassMap I have the below code:**
csvConfig.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<decimal?>().NumberStyle =
NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowExponent;

Ex: "000120000" -> "1200.00"  (right now i am getting the value as "120000")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it. With a custom converter.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,MoveDecimalPoint,NoMoveDecimalPoint");
            writer.WriteLine("1,000120000,000120000");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal MoveDecimalPoint { get; set; }
    public decimal NoMoveDecimalPoint { get; set; }
}

public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.MoveDecimalPoint).TypeConverter<MoveDecimalConverter>();
    }
}

public class MoveDecimalConverter : DecimalConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var numberStyle = memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.NumberStyle ?? NumberStyles.Number;

        if (decimal.TryParse(text, numberStyle, memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.CultureInfo, out var d))
        {
            return d / 100;
        }

        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to have ALL decimal values move two decimal places, you could add the `MoveDecimalConverter` to the configuration.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,MoveDecimalPoint,NoMoveDecimalPoint");
            writer.WriteLine("1,000120000,000120000");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new MoveDecimalConverter());

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `ConvertUsing()`

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,MoveDecimalPoint,NoMoveDecimalPoint");
            writer.WriteLine("1,000120000,000120000");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal MoveDecimalPoint { get; set; }
    public decimal NoMoveDecimalPoint { get; set; }
}

public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.MoveDecimalPoint).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(row["MoveDecimalPoint"], NumberStyles.Number, row.Configuration.CultureInfo, out var d))
            {
                return d / 100;
            } 
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This Helps, Thanks David. Do you know of any other ways in achieving the required output?

Comment: I added a `ConvertUsing()` example.  Ultimately I believe you will have to manually do the division by 100. There is no formatting you can use.  Formatting will only format the number you have. You need the number transformed to a number that is 1/100 the size of the original number.

Comment: Your other option would be to do string manipulation and put a period in the location you want for the decimal and then use `decimal.Parse` or `decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: FYI.  If you want ALL decimal values to move the decimal place, you could use the first example and you wouldn't need the `FooClassMap`. Just replace `csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();` with `csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new MoveDecimalConverter());`

Comment: i would still have to use FooClassMap as there are other fields that need mapping differently reading from the file. So i guess the first example would work just fine. Need to do some null checks for the text and then do decimal parse. Thanks for your inputs on this issue.

Comment: Or you could use both.  `csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter` wouldn't have to replace the `csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap`.